# Making an Action Button re-read file and recompute in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I've written a script to calculate glicko ratings and produce odds and historic plots for sport teams. A separate script is responsible for querying the SQL server that holds historic data and extracting the relevant info to make a local tsv file of the info I need for the rating calculation. To make it more user-friendly, I've put the functions into a simple shiny app.

My problem is that I would like to put in a button that automatically executes the code of the second script that adds recent matches to the data file, so the ratings can be updated.

I've proved a simplified example of my code, showing that I'm handling the bulk of the data wrangling and preparation of the ratings object, from where I can get probabilities, before defining the UI. I tried a simple example of modifying the teams_list with my action button, but this did not recalculate the list of teams available to enter in *selectInput()*; because of how *observeEvent()* handles the code with *isolate()* to avoid recalculations, I'm guessing. So simply duplicating all the code that loads data and prepares the ratings object will not do unless it makes all the rest of the code re-evaluate its input.

I considered moving all of that into the action button and deleting it from the start of the script, but that would mean that there is *no* data at all until the action button would be pressed and that is not desirable either. I don't want to query the database more often than is necessary, so it is a must to be able to run the app from the existing data rather than querying it every time the app is launched.

Does anyone have a suggestion for how this could be accomplished?

```
### Toy example

## Prep: This input data normally exists before app is run.
library(tidyverse)

tibble(team1 = c("Name1", "Name2", "Name3", "Name2"),
       team2 = c("Name2", "Name1", "Name1", "Name3"),
       team1Won = c(T, T, F, T)) %>%
  write_tsv("example_match_file.tsv")

## Here the app code starts.
# Loading data and calculating team ratings

match_df <- read_tsv("example_match_file.tsv")

rating_calculation <- function(match_data = match_df) {
  match_data %>%
    group_by(team1) %>% 
    summarize(matchesWon = sum(team1Won)) %>%
    arrange(desc(matchesWon))
}

rating_df <- rating_calculation(match_df)
team_list <- rating_df$team1

odds_calculation <- function(team1, team2, ratingObject = rating_df) {
  #Real calculation omitted for brevity
  p <- runif(1)
}

## Define Shiny UI
library(shiny)
ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Odds"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput(inputId = "team1",
                  label = "Team 1",
                  choices = team_list),
      
      selectInput(inputId = "team2",
                  label = "Team 2",
                  choices = team_list),
      #actionButton("update", "Update match data")
    ), 
    mainPanel(
      tableOutput("odds")
    )
  )
)

## Define Shiny server logic
server <- function(input, output) {
  #Generate Odds
  output$odds <- renderTable({
    p <- odds_calculation(rating_df, input$team1, input$team2)
    tibble(Team = c(input$team1, input$team2), Win = c(p, 1-p)) %>%
      mutate(Odds = (1/Win))
  })
  
  ### Make Action Button update database, re-read example_match_file.tsv and rerun all calculations.
  # datasetInput <- observeEvent(input$update, {
  #  ???
  #   })
  
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm reading this right you'd like to spare your query limit by providing a local set of data to your shiny application. But if a user requests an update you'd like to trigger a query to be used in calculations.

I cannot recommend enough that you make full use of reactivity in Shiny. It is fairly rare to use an object from the global environment, especially when you intend for user inputs to manipulate those objects. You should have your base data ( in your case the tsv) load into the global environment, and then call that information into your application via a `reactive dataframe`. I built the below minimal example using `mpg` subset to the first 5 rows to simulate the .tsv on your local machine. `mpg` subset to 10 rows is to simulate the results of a query to a database. These two data sets get called via an `if else` statement dependent on an `actionbutton`.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(shiny)

# using partial mpg data to simulate un-updated data
mpg <- ggplot2::mpg[1:5,]

ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      actionButton("update", "Update Data"),
      uiOutput('selectOpts')
    ),
    mainPanel(
     h2("This is our base data layer"),
     verbatimTextOutput('print_interval1'),
     h2("This is our output data"),
     verbatimTextOutput('print_interval2')
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  
  # The core of shiny is the reactivity. It's the workhorse of interactive apps.
  # If possible, a data calculation should always happen in a reactive context. 
  working_data <- reactive({
    
    # actionbuttons increment a value by 1, starting with 0. If input < 0 the
    # user has not interacted yet. If incremented again, the reactive context
    # will invalidate and re-calculate the working_data() object
    if (input$update < 1) {
      base_dat <- 
        mpg %>%
        mutate(ratio = cty/hwy)
    } else {
      base_dat <- 
        ggplot2::mpg[1:10,] %>% # calling from namespace to simulate a query. Full data
        mutate(ratio = cty/hwy)
    }
    
    # return our base data. Can be called with `working_data()`
    data.frame(base_dat)
    
  })
  
  output$print_interval1 <- renderPrint({
    working_data()
  })
  
  output$selectOpts <- renderUI({
    # using the reactive data inside renderUI we can be flexible in our options
    # this lets us adapt the UI to reactive data. 
    radioButtons('model',
                "Select Model",
                sort(unique(working_data()$model)))
  })
  
  # You can also chain reactive objects. 
  output_data <- reactive({
    working_data() %>%
      group_by(model) %>%
      filter(model == input$model) %>%
      summarise(m.ratio = mean(ratio))
  })
  
  output$print_interval2 <- renderPrint({
    output_data() %>%
      data.table()
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

I also recommend looking into this [post about database syncing](https://roh.engineering/posts/2020/08/shiny-in-production-app-and-database-syncing/) for setting up triggers and using reactive objects as your applications get more complex. I hope that's enough to get you on the right track for both your initial question about updating data, and your comments about having your inputs react to updated data.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation; I'm still learning how reactive() works, didn't occour to me that you could define it like so.

Comment: This brings me into another difficulty, however: When I move the code to read the input files into the server chunk, the selectInput() fails as it cannot find the team_list object. 
In the server, I've tried defining it as team_list or output$team_list but neither works. (And since this depends on the code for the odds object, this would bring me back to the beginning of defining everything in the global chunk.
Do you have any idea how to make it accessible to selectInput() in ui?

Comment: Since your data is mutable, you want it to be reactive. If you have an input that relies on reactive data you'll want to use [renderUI](https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/latest/renderUI.html) to make a mutable input. I'll come back this evening when I have more time and create an example with your reprex.

Comment: Thanks!
Otherwise, I got it to work if I accept that the team list not be updated from its initial state, which is sufficient for my current use, but would not do if the application is not restarted regularly. I will definitely have to read up on renderUI to see how it works.